# How to find the number of positive and negative examples in my training dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning

In my dataset each object is represented by a 28x28 dimensional image in a single 'flattened' 784 dimensional vector with an associated label (+1 or -1).
I want to find the number of -1 and +1 labelled images.

I have tried,

```
In :: data2.min(), data2.max()
```

But it gives me the output of

```
Out :: (0.0, 255.0)
```

which is the Image id, not labels.

Comment: Where are your labels stored in? If they are in a list, use `len()`, if in an array, use `.shape`, if they are stored in pandas dataframe use `.value_counts()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the image pixels colors, you won't find the labels there.
If it is a familiar dataset it should have an associated labels file or a CSV file with the last column as a label.